# \@seccntformat only for section

Tags: sectioning, numbering, punctuation

I would like to add a dot between the number of the section and section name. I used

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
\csname the#1\endcsname .}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that, obviously, it put a dot also among subsection number and subsection name *which I do not want*. Is it possible to add the dot only between section number and section *using low level instructions i.e. without any additional package*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a `\ifx\....` comparison

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter


\DeclareRobustCommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \def\temp@@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@@b{section}%
  \ifx\temp@@a\temp@@b
  \csname the#1\endcsname .\quad%
  \else
  \csname the#1\endcsname\quad%
  \fi
} 


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

How about

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable indiv. control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}
\makeatother
```

Feel free to use a different spacing amount than `\quad`.

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable indiv. control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\subsection{Good Morning}
\subsubsection{Yawn}
\section{Goodbye World}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The OP has asked me to explain a bit how this code works. It's helpful to begin with the default definition of the `\@seccntformat` macro that's provided by the LaTeX kernel (see the file `latex.ltx`):

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

The macro's argument, `#1`, is a string of the form `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph`, or `subparagraph`. Upon expansion, the macro will thus return `\thesection\quad`, `\thesubsection\quad`, etc. Observe that there is no `.` ("dot", "full stop") before `\quad`.

The proposed modified form of the macro is:

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable indiv. control
```

The first thing the redefined macro does is to check if the macro `\#1@cntformat` is "undefined". (As above, `#1` is a string of the form `section`, `subsection`, etc.) If `\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}` is true, the "true" branch is followed. Suppose, for instance, that `#1` is set to `subsubsection`. Assuming `\subsubsection@cntformat` hasn't been defined before `\@seccntformat` is executed, the "true" branch is chosen, and thus `\@seccntformat` expands to `\thesubsubsection\quad`.

If, in contrast, `#1` is set to `section`, `\section@cntformat` will in fact have been defined by the time `\@seccntformat` is executed. Specifically, the solution given above provides:

```
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\quad}
```

Hence, the "false" branch of `\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}` is followed, `\@seccntformat#1` evaluates to `\section@cntformat` which, in turn, evaluates to `\thesection.\quad`.

Comparing this approach with the one in Christian Hupfer's answer is useful. Christian's version of `\@seccntformat` begins by setting up two "scratch" macros; the first is set to `section` and the other to (the contents of) `#1`. Then the `\ifx` conditional is applied to compare the two macros. If the condition is 'true', which will only be the case if `#1` is equal to the string `section`, `\thesection.\quad` is executed; otherwise, `\csname the#1\endcsname\quad` is executed. If you're only ever going to redefine the look of the formatted `section` counter, both approaches are equally good. If, for some reason not revealed so far, you also needed to change the looks of the formatted `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph`, and `subparagraph` counters, the approach above may be a bit more straightforward to implement. Let me state that this statement shouldn't be taken to imply some kind of criticism of Christian's solution!

Comment: Your solution of course work, but I didn't understand how. In particular where is that I decide that the non-default command is for section only? What if I would like to format section in a way, subsection in another, subsubsection again differently?

Comment: I had only `section` in mind, of course, I am aware that my solution is not extendible to other section levels  ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I'm definitely not criticizing your approach at all. For sure, the OP indicated an interest only in modifying the formatted `section` counter, and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

Under regular documents, using `\pdfstrcmp` (e-TeX) should work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname% Print sectional counter
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}=0 .\fi% If \section, print .
  \quad% Space between number and title
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Since `\@seccntformat` receives a single argument for the sectional unit counter, we string-compare the argument against `section`. `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}` returns 0 if `<strA>` matches `<strB>`.

Answer (score 3):

With a KOMA-Script class there is no need to redefine an internal command. You only have to redefine `\sectionformat`:

```
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection.\enskip}
```

But maybe there should be also a dot between between section number and section title in the page header:

```
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\thesection.\enskip}
```

and in TOC

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\tocentrynumberwithdot
]{section}
\newcommand\tocentrynumberwithdot[1]{\renewcommand\autodot{.}#1}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=noenddot% <- no dot at the end of numbers
]{scrartcl}
% replace \autodot by . for section titles in document
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection.\enskip}

% replace \autodot by . for section titles in page header
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{\thesection.\enskip}

% % replace \autodot by . for section titles in TOC
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\tocentrynumberwithdot
]{section}
\newcommand\tocentrynumberwithdot[1]{\renewcommand\autodot{.}#1}

\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

No `\if`s required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\sectionsuffix      {.}
\def\subsectionsuffix   {}
\def\subsubsectionsuffix{}
\def\paragraphsuffix    {}

\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname%
  \csname#1suffix\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{My section\label{s:B}}
\subsection{My subsection\label{s:BB}}
\subsubsection{My subsubsection}
In sections \ref{s:B} and \ref{s:BB}, a refed section does NOT end in a dot, which is essential.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just another variation of the same basic idea.  It has the slight advantage that the `\ifx` test is purely expandable, should this ever be a concern.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname \c@section
    .%
  \fi
  \quad
} 


\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Contents of section Foo

\subsection{Bar}
Contents of subsection Bar

\end{document}
```