# \hyperref and modified \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, titletoc

I'm using `hyperref` (and `titletoc`) package(s). I redefined `\appendix` that way

```
\newif\if@appendix\@appendixfalse
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\setcounter{subsection}{0}%
\gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%
\@appendixtrue
}
```

`\@appendix` if is needed to modify the heading title, as i asked before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308737/seccntformat-only-for-section):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%                     
 \def\temp@@a{#1}%
 \def\temp@@b{section}%
 \ifx\temp@@a\temp@@b                                          
  \if@appendix
   \csname the#1\endcsname :\quad%                              
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname .\quad%
  \fi
  \else                                                         
   \csname the#1\endcsname\quad%                                
  \fi
  }
```

and

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection%
 {section}{0}{0mm}%
 {2\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
 {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\scshape
 \if@appendix{%
  Appendix~%
  }\fi
}%
```

}

**in practice** if I'm writing

```
  subsection            ==> x.y subsection_name
  section_not_appendix  ==> x. section_name
  section_appendix      ==> Appendix x: appendix_name
```

for the moment I got what I wanted *without* using any other package *which I would like possibly not to use*.

**My question is**: Now I want to modify toc entry in the table of contents, in particular I would like to have such format

```
  Apppendix x: appendix_name
```

where x is also an hyperref linking to the appendix.
I think that the easiest way to proceed (*without adding any other packages*) is to modify further the definition of `\section` in order to change the `\addcontentesline` command which should sit in it.
Can anyone help me?

## **EDIT**

A minimal example is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true
 ,urlcolor=blue
 ,anchorcolor=blue
 ,citecolor=blue
 ,filecolor=blue
 ,linkcolor=blue
 ,menucolor=blue
 ,linktocpage=true
 ,bookmarks=true
 ,unicode=true
 ,pdfcreator={XeLaTeX}
 ,pdfa=true
]{hyperref}           

\makeatletter                                                   
 \renewcommand\section{\@startsection%
  {section}{0}{0mm}%
  {2\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\scshape
  \if@appendix{%
   Appendix~%
  }\fi
  }%
 }

 \renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection%                       
  {subsection}{1}{0mm}%
  {1\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}%
 }

 \DeclareRobustCommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%                     
  \def\temp@@a{#1}%
  \def\temp@@b{section}%
  \ifx\temp@@a\temp@@b                                          
   \if@appendix
    \csname the#1\endcsname :\quad%                              
   \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname .\quad%
   \fi
  \else                                                         
   \csname the#1\endcsname\quad%                             
  \fi
 } 

\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \section*{\contentsname
  \@mkboth{%
   \contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
  \addvspace{32\p@\@plus14\p@}%
  %\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\contentsname}
 }

 \newif\if@appendix\@appendixfalse
 \renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%
  \@appendixtrue
  }

\makeatother

\titlecontents{section}%                                        
  [9mm]                                                         
  {}                                                            
  {\contentslabel[%                                             
   \hyperlink{%
    section.\thecontentslabel
   }{%
    \thecontentslabel.%
    }]%
  {7mm}}
  {\hspace*{-7mm}}                                              
  {\hfill\contentspage}                                         
  {}                                                            

\titlecontents{subsection}%                                     
  [20mm]                                                        
  {}                                                            
  {\contentslabel[                                              
   \hyperlink{%
    subsection.\thecontentslabel%
   }{%
    \thecontentslabel%
    }]%
  {12mm}}%
  {\hspace*{-12mm}}                                             
  {\hfill\contentspage}                                        
  {}                                                           

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \section{First}
 \subsection{First-first}
 \subsection{First-second}
 \section{Second}
 \section*{Unnumbered}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Unnumbered}
 \subsection{Second-First}
 \appendix
 \section{This is the app}
\end{document}
```

The output of the table of contents the one I want to get *except* for the fact that I would like to have the appendix entry almost like the unnumbered entry: I would like it to be

```
 Appendix A: This is the app
```

with the `A` a hyperref to the appendix. How can i do?

Comment: Can you provide at least some working document to work with. Is `titletoc` really necessary?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the attention. I edited the question adding an example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a solution, it's enough to define

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{section}{0}%
 \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
 \gdef\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}%
 \@appendixtrue
 \titlecontents{section}%                                        
  [2mm]                                                         
  {}                                                            
  {Appendix~%                                             
  \hyperlink{%
   section.\thecontentslabel
   }{%
  \thecontentslabel.~%
   }%
  }
 {\hspace*{-7mm}}                                              
 {\hfill\contentspage}                                         
 {} 
 }
```

Comment: You are probably receiving some "duplicate destination" warnings. Add `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{appendix.\thesection}` to your `\appendix` command.

Comment: @Werner I found another problem: the number of the section are no more clickable! How can I fix this?