# How to add a period after a section number, but not after subsection

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, punctuation, sections-paragraphs

I am currently writing my master thesis and have some specifications with the numbering. My professor wants my numbering as followed:

```
1. section  
1.1 subsection  
1.1.1 subsubsection
```

I need a period after the section, but not after the subsections. I am using `scrartcl` and already tried: `numbers=autoendperiod` and `numbers=endperiod`. There also seems to be a problem with `\usepackage{titlesec}`, as I am getting some errors when I try to use it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that similar question was asked before ... quick solution: in preamble add `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsubsection}.}
` . Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: With a KOMA-Script class there is no need to redefine an internal command like `\@seccntformat`. You can use option `numbers=noenddot` and redefine KOMA-Script command `\sectionformat` which is described in the documentation. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370091/43317 because the question here was closed.