# How to customize style of section and subsection numbers when used in headers?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, xstring

TL;DR - Why am I getting errors with the last line of

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\alph{section})}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\StrGobbleRight{\thesection}{1}.\roman{subsection})}
```

I am new to Latex (using Overleaf) and trying to automatically update the section and subsection labelling using `xstring` and `StrGobbleRight{}{}`.

Specifically, I would like the subsections to be labelled with the section's (alphabetical) label, which is followed by a bracket, followed by the subsection's (roman) label.

For instance:

> a) Chapter 1
>
> > a.i) Initial
> > ...
> > a.ix) Last

> b) Chapter 2
>
> > b.i) Initial
> > ...
> > b.ix) Last

etc.

I would also like this to automatically update in the table of contents.

For the sections, I managed to get it to work using

```
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\alph{section})}
```

For the subsections, when I use `\StrGobbleRight{\thesection}{1}` I get the alphabetic label of the section correctly. However, when I then try to use this in the context of

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\StrGobbleRight{\thesection}{1}.\roman{subsection})}
```

a whole load of errors come up. I believe the error is to do with the removal of the bracket.

Any help on how to correct this, and some explanation as to where my understanding is flawed, would be great!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: xstring commands are not expandable which is causing the error just define `\thesection` to be `\alph{section}` and `\thesubsection` to be `\thesection.\roman{subsection}` and add the `)` as part of the section formatting, not part of the number

Comment: And here begins my introduction into "expandable commands"! [For any other beginners](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_does_%5Cexpandafter_work%3A_The_meaning_of_expansion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I revised -- and simplified -- this answer after the OP clarified how cross-references to section- and subsection-level headers should look like.)

As David Carlisle has already noted in a comment, your formatting objective doesn't require the `xstring` package. Instead of `\StrGobbleRight{\thesection}{1}`, the following solution simply uses `\alph{section}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section})}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{section}.\roman{subsection})}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip

\section{Chapter 1}
\subsection{Initial \dots}
\addtocounter{subsection}{7}
\subsection{Last \dots} \label{sec:a.ix}

\section{Chapter 2}
\subsection{Initial \dots} \label{sec:b.i}
\addtocounter{subsection}{7}
\subsection{Last \dots}

As argued in subsections \ref{sec:a.ix} and \ref{sec:b.i}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! In case any other readers are looking for further information, Mico explains this more in depth [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308737/seccntformat-only-for-section). Two queries:        

1.  Can you explain @cntformat some more? Is it comparable to a "method" of the "class" \thesection?  

2.  The only issue I can see is that the bracket in the header title isn't then replicated in the table of contents, is there an easy way to extend this?

Comment: @user13964861 - Let me obtain some more clarity as to what you're trying to achieve. I had been operating under the assumption that the `)` decorative element should *not* show up in cross-references. (Cf. what `\ref` does in the answer above.) If this working assumption is valid, the `)` element shouldn't show up in the ToC either. However, your follow-up comment suggests that my working assumption is, in fact, invalid. Please clarify whether the `)` element should show up in cross-references to section- and subsection-level headers.

Comment: The `)` element should show up in cross-references to the section and subsection-level headers.

Comment: @user13964861 - Many thanks for this clarification. This actually simplifies the job *a lot*. I'll post a revised answer in shortly.

Comment: Ah - thanks, that is a lot simpler. Thanks for your patience with me!